# Azure IoT Edge Service Not Starting

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to work with IoT Edge. To create an Iot Edge Device for development purposes, I'm following the instructions provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-windows-with-windows). I can successfully get to the line that says `Start-Service iotedge`. Unfortunately, the "iotedge" Windows Service will not start.

I can see the "iotedge" Windows Service in the Service management console. When I manually click "Start", I receive the following message after a couple of seconds:

*The iotedge service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.*

When I look in the Event Viewer, I see the following Error in the Application Windows logs:

*The description for Event ID 1 from source iotedged cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event: 
iotedged::windows -- Error while running service. Quitting.*

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 1803 in a Boot Camp partition.

On this same partition, I've tried running Azure IoT Edge on Virtual Machines in Hyper-V running:

- Windows Server 2016
- Windows 10 Pro

In both cases, the "iotedge" Windows Service fails to start.

I've also have a Virtual Machine hosted on Azure that's running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter in a Standard DS1 v2 (1 vcpus, 3.5 GB memory) instance. I'm unable to get the iotedge Windows Service to run there.

Does the iotedge Windows Service run in a virtualized environment? Even if it doesn't the service should work in the Window 10 Enterprise environment which is an actual partition. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: One reason the service would start and then stop is if something isn't right in the config.yaml file. Did you complete the steps in the [configure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-windows-with-windows#configure-the-azure-iot-edge-security-daemon) section of the how-to guide? You need the device connection string, the edge device's hostname, "connect" and "listen" URLs for management and workload APIs, and moby runtime info.

IoT Edge does run in a virtualized Windows environment--that's how it gets tested in the team's internal build infrastructure.

Comment: Azure IoT Edge dev here (as is _Damon Barry_). Firstly, you can get rid of that warning in the event logs about "description not found" by importing the registry entries as [given in the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-windows-with-windows#install-the-azure-iot-edge-security-daemon). Yes, the install experience on Windows is not ideal and we're working on an installer.

Also, it'll be good to get some more logs. The "Verify successful installation" section of the doc has the powershell command you can run to get additional logs.

Comment: @DamonBarry & Raj - Thank you so much! The problem was the configure section. Basically, I was running the "Start-Service" command on the "Create and start the IoT Edge service." step. I noticed the service wasn't started in the Windows Services console, and basically assumed I had done something wrong. Once I got the config section completed, it started right up. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChadCampbell Great...converted my comment to an answer. Would be great if you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason the service would start and then stop is if something isn't right in the config.yaml file. Did you complete the steps in the [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-windows-with-windows#configure-the-azure-iot-edge-security-daemon) section of the how-to guide? You need the device connection string, the edge device's hostname, "connect" and "listen" URLs for management and workload APIs, and moby runtime info. IoT Edge does run in a virtualized Windows environment--that's how it gets tested in the team's internal build infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

In the EventViewer message, I noticed "The description for Event ID 1 from source **iotedged** cannot be found..."

Should it be **iotedge**?

By any chance did you make a typo when you create IoT Edge service?

Comment: I thought the same thing. However, that does not seem to be the case. The `C:\ProgramData\iotedge` directory includes both a **iotedge.exe** and an **iotedged.exe**. I'm not sure of the difference between the two. I tried them both. Regardless, the docs reference iotedge**d**.exe.  Thank you for sharing your idea though.

Comment: The "d" in iotedged.exe stands for daemon...that's the binary that runs as a Windows service. iotedge.exe is a CLI that admins can use to list/start/stop modules when troubleshooting, etc.